# Как рассчитать угол наклона объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика, координаты

Стрела летит с первого объекта в к другому. Как рассчитать угол вращения стрелы по оси **Z**, так что бы она как бы летела с первого объекта к объекту **#2**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расчет баллистической траектории?

Comment: Нет, просто что бы стрела была повернута к 2 объекту

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vector2 PointA = new Vector2(1, 1);
Vector2 PointB = new Vector2(2, 2);
Vector2 VectorAB = PointB-PointA;
float AngleAB = Mathf.Atan2(VectorAB.y, VectorAB.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
Debug.Log("Angle:"+AngleAB);
```

`Angle:45`

---

Либо [ObjectTransform.LookAt(TargetTransform)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).